# Jupyter Notebook Beginner Problem writing a function

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I'm struggling with this problem in Jupyter Notebook. Any help would be appreciated :)

Write out what the function call would look like to get a result of 25 from the following function:

```
def my_multiplier(argOne, argTwo):
   return argOne * argTwo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at this function, it's multiplying the two parameters:

```
def my_multiplier(argOne, argTwo): 
    return argOne * argTwo
```

The way this works, is when you call the function, the values specified becomes the *parameters* `argOne` and `argTwo`.

So if we call the `my_multiplier()` with say `(3, 7)`, in your function `argOne` contains a value of `3` and `argTwo` a value of `7`.  The asterisk `*` symbol in this case indicates a multiplication operation.  So the function is returning the values of the two parameters multiplied together.

```
def my_multiplier(argOne, argTwo): 
    return argOne * argTwo

result = my_multiplier(3, 7)
print("my_multiplier returns " + str( result ) )
```

Which would output:

```
my_multiplier returns 21
```

Can you work out the answer on your own now?